# what does "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException" mean?

Tags: java, exception, io

I have been tasked with creating a simple java program that reads grades in a data file, then counts how many grades are within each of the following groups: [90 - 100] [80 - 89] [70 - 79] [60 - 69] [below 60] Here is the sample output: [90 - 100] 10 [80 - 89] 9 [70 - 79] 20 [60 - 69] 8 [below 60] 2.

this is what i have coded so far:

```
//Import the needed header files
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


//Class
public class GradeDistribution
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
  //Sets up varaibles and assign string numbers to int values
  Scanner input=new Scanner(new File(args[0])); 

    //Declare the needed varaibles and initialize them
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    int count4 = 0;
    int count5 = 0;
    int sCount = 0;



    //Loop to read till the "data.txt" has scores
    while(input.hasNextInt())
    {
        //Increment score counter
        sCount++;

        //Read scores
        input.nextInt();
    }



    //Score array
    int score[] = new int[sCount];

    //Loop to iterate through the scores
    for(int i=0;i<sCount;i++)
    {
        //Read
        score[i]=input.nextInt();

        //Check condition for [90-100]
        if (score[i]<=100 && score[i]>=90)
        {
            //Increment count1
            count1 = count1 + 1;               
        }

        //Check condition for [80-89]
        else if (score[i]<90 && score[i]>=80)
        {
            //Increment count2
            count2 = count2 + 1;               
        }

        //Check condition for [70-79]
        else if (score[i]<80 && score[i]>=70)
        {
            //Increment count3
            count3 = count3 + 1;               
        }

        //Check condition for [60-69]
        else if (score[i]<70 && score[i]>=60)
        {
            //Increment count4
            count4 = count4 + 1;               
        }   

        //Otherwise below 60
        else
        {
            //Increment count5
            count5 = count5 + 1;               
        }                       
    }

    //Print
    System.out.println("[90-100] "+count1);
    System.out.println("[80-89] "+count2);
    System.out.println("[70-79] "+count3);   
    System.out.println("[60-69] "+count4);       
    System.out.println("[below 60] "+count5);       
}
 }
```

the code looked and logically was executable, but when i run it i recieve this error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException 
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) 
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) 
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) 
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) 
 at GradeDistribution.main(GradeDistribution.java:43)
```

why is that?

Comment: You're looping until `hasNextInt()` is false. Why would you expect `nextInt()` to work afterwards?

Comment: There is no `nextInt()` because you exhaust all `int`s in your first `while` loop. You're not saving anything! `nextInt()` doesn't magically start over again when you go to your next loop.

Comment: Googled for the exception name and found [this amazing sentence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) which answers your question - _Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type._

Comment: @user10101010 Is my answer below acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.InputMismatchException` is when you use `Scanner` to accept a certain type(such as an `int`, `String`, or `char`), but a different type is inputted. For example if you call `nextInt()` and you input a `String`, this exception will be thrown.

The issue in your code is probably in your first `while` loop, where you call `input.nextInt()`. This only checks for integers, whereas your file may have contained a String.

Answer (score 0):

Because you iterate incorrectly.
What;s the purpose of this code? And then iterating again?:

```
  //Loop to read till the "data.txt" has scores
    while(input.hasNextInt())
    {
        //Increment score counter
        sCount++;

        //Read scores
        input.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: It is more likely because he is iterating the scanner all the way, and then calling that line on an empty scanner. It has to be instantiated again.